# Displaying full screen image in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, image, xamarin.forms

I have a cross platform application that is built using Xamarin Forms. The application contains images grid. I want to display full screen image with ability to zoom the image when user click on image. I search and I found some solutions. One of the solutions says:

1. Create new page contains image (say ImagePage). like this:

> ```
> <ContentPage.Content>
>         <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
>             <Image HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="ScreenImage"></Image>
>         </StackLayout>
>     </ContentPage.Content>
> ```

2. When user clicks on image, the navigation goes to ImagePage to display the image.

The problem with this solution is that it doesn't support zoom. My question is that the best solution? Is there a plugin that perform this job?

If the above solution is the best, how can I implement zooming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at "Adding a Pinch Gesture Recognizer" - a common scenario for the pinch gesture is to perform interactive zoom of an image at the pinch location:  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/gestures/pinch/

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem and i fixed using the syncfusion control.
([syncfusion zooming](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sfimageeditor/zooming))
syncfusion have the community license for your control and this is free.([communitylicense](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense))

xaml:

```
<imageeditor:SfImageEditor EnableZooming="true"  MaximumZoomLevel="8"/>
```

if you want, i can help you fr configurated syncfusion in your solution